# unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in Base ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I'm Using pagemenu project https://github.com/uacaps/PageMenu to include in my app the segmented control to switch between view controllers,this control consists in one base view controller(PageMenuViewController1) and two child view controllers (ViewController1, ViewController2) but when I launch this PageMenuViewController1 the app fails in the child view controllers(below I show exactly where the app fails) and throws this error:

```js
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

below you can see the code for the viewcontrollers.

The base View Controller is:

```js
class PageMenuViewController1: UIViewController {

  var pageMenu : CAPSPageMenu?

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    // Array to keep track of controllers in page menu
    var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []

    // Create variables for all view controllers you want to put in the
    // page menu, initialize them, and add each to the controller array.
    // (Can be any UIViewController subclass)
    // Make sure the title property of all view controllers is set
    // Example:
    var controller1 : ViewController1 = ViewController1()
    controller1.title = "ViewController1"
    controllerArray.append(controller1)
    var controller2 : ViewController2 = ViewController2()
    controller2.title = "ViewController2"
    controllerArray.append(controller2)

    // Customize page menu to your liking (optional) or use default settings by sending nil for 'options' in the init
    // Example:
    var parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
      .MenuItemSeparatorWidth(4.3),
      .UseMenuLikeSegmentedControl(true),
      .MenuItemSeparatorPercentageHeight(0.1)
    ]

    // Initialize page menu with controller array, frame, and optional parameters
    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)

    // Lastly add page menu as subview of base view controller view
    // or use pageMenu controller in you view hierachy as desired
    self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)
  }
}
```

the Child View Controllers:

-- ViewController1

```js
class ViewController1: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource{

  @IBOutlet var tableview:UITableView!

  let apiClient = ApiClient()

  var clubs: [Club]!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    apiClient.Service.getList() { clubs, error in
      if clubs != nil {
        self.clubs = clubs
        self.tableview.reloadData()// Here is where the lldb throws the exception
      }
      else {
        println("error: \(error)")
      }
    }
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.clubs?.count ?? 0
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) ->UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("clubObjectCell") as! ClubTableViewCell
    cell.clubObject = self.clubs?[indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }

}
```

-- ViewController2

```js
class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource {

  @IBOutlet var tableview:UITableView!

  let apiClient = ApiClient()

  var parties: [Party]? = []

  override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    apiClient.partiesService.getList() { parties, error in
      if parties != nil {
        self.parties = parties
        self.tableview.reloadData()// Here is where the lldb throws the exception
      }
      else {
        println("error: \(error)")
      }
    }
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.parties?.count ?? 0
  }

  func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("partyObjectCell") as! PartyTableViewCell
    cell.partyObject = self.parties?[indexPath.row]
    return cell
  }

}
```

I hope my issue it's clear :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you forgot to connect the `tableView` `IBOutlet` property to a view in your storyboard. In the gutter, to the left of the line of code that says `@IBOutlet var tableview: UITableView!`, you should see a circle. If the circle is filled, then the outlet is already connected. But if the circle is empty, you need to connect it.

This connection can be made in a few different ways. A common method is to use the Assistant Editor. Open `ViewController1.swift` on one pane, and open `Main.storyboard` on the other pane. Select the appropriate `UITableView` in the Storyboard. Then, control-drag to the empty circle near the `IBoutlet` in `ViewController1`.

If your outlet is already connected (you can see a full circle), then you should try moving the `reloadData()` call to `viewWillAppear(:)` like so:

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    apiClient.Service.getList() { clubs, error in
        if clubs != nil {
            self.clubs = clubs
            self.tableview.reloadData()// Here is where the lldb throws the exception
        }
        else {
            println("error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the properties are already linked in the storyboard, the child view controllers works perfectly out of this control, what do you refer with **you should try moving the reloadData() call to viewWillAppear(:)** ? could you explain me a little bit more please?

Comment: @Edu Sure thing. The IBOutlets may not be set when viewDidLoad() is called. However, they should be set by the time viewWillAppear(:) is called. So, even though the outlets are connected at design time, they aren't actually usable until after the point where you're trying to use them. I've updated my answer to clarify what I mean.

Comment: sorry @ndmeiri, when I push on the baseViewController tabbar item, the func viewWillAppear in viewController1(default) is called twice. ->  **println PageMenuViewController1 viewWillAppear
println ClubsController viewWillAppear
println ClubsController viewWillAppear**

Answer (score 1):

I think the way you are instantiating ViewController1 and ViewController2 is not correct.

If you are using storyboard then you must instantiate as follows:

```
var controller1 : ViewController1 = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("<view controller 1 identifier in storyboard>")
```

If you are not using storyboard then you must instantiate using NSBundle.mainModule().loadNibNamed(...).

Just calling the class initializer will not attach them to the storyboard or xib.